# eglCreateWindowSurface on ICS, and switching from 2D to 3D

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nativewindow, egl

I'm trying to make an NDK-based game work on Android ICS. It worked fine on Honeycomb and Gingerbread.

The game uses some 2D rendering, some 3D rendering, switching between the two at various stages of execution. (This is not negotiable due to third-party code.) We're using `ANativeWindow_lock()`/`ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost()` for the 2D rendering, and `eglCreateWindowSurface()`/`gl*()`/`eglSwapBuffers()` for the 3D rendering.

On Honeycomb and Gingerbread this all worked fine. On ICS, `eglCreateWindowSurface()` fails with the following messages in the log:

```
E/SurfaceTexture( 1765): [com.fnord/com.fnord.MyActivity] connect: already connected (cur=2, req=1)
E/libEGL  ( 5466): EGLNativeWindowType 0x29e9b8 already connected to another API
E/libEGL  ( 5466): eglCreateWindowSurface:374 error 300b (EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW)
E/libEGL  ( 5466): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Looking at the source code it seems pretty obvious that `eglCreateWindowSurface()` is failing because something's got the native window open for 2D rendering and it won't let me change it to 3D without somehow releasing the surface first. However, the ANativeWindow API doesn't seem to have any obvious way to do this.

Has anyone else run into this, and what's the solution?

**Updated**

So I've rewritten my 2D rendering code to use OpenGL primitives instead (upload backbuffer to a texture, render texture via a pair of triangles, swapbuffers). This works up to a point. *Now* what's happening is that the 2D rendering works fine; then I destroy the surface, create a new one in preparation for 3D rendering, and the second call to `eglCreateWindowSurface()` fails. This time, with:

```
E/SurfaceTexture( 1869): [com.fnord/com.fnord.MyActivity] connect: already connected (cur=1, req=1)
```

...and it throws an EGL error of `AEGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW`.

Note that the new surface is created with *precisely the same attributes* as the old one. I've even tried making sure I call `eglTerminate()` / `eglInitialize()` between the two calls to `eglCreateWindowSurface()`.

Is it the case that I can use each ANativeWindow precisely once? If so, doesn't that fail Khronos' EGL conformance tests? Is there a way to get NativeActivity to recreate the window, then?

**Updated updated**

Turns out that the last problem was caused by me failing to call `eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT)` before destroying the context and surface. This was causing the destruction to be delayed until the thread unbound the context and surface, which of course it wasn't, so causing the call to `eglCreateWindowSurface()` to legitimately fail (you can't have two window surfaces on the same native window).

This is a *bit* counterintuitive, because one would assume that calling `eglTerminate()` would destroy all EGL resources, but allowed for by the spec. Be warned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a supported use case. The fact that it worked before was just luck for you and it could fail on some devices. You can work around this by rendering either the 2D or 3D content in a different window, or render the 2D content in a Bitmap that you then use as a GL texture, etc.

Comment: Do you have a link for a reference for this? i.e., what functionality is guaranteed to be supported?

Comment: I rewrote my code to do 2D rendering via OpenGL --- but it still doesn't work. Details in body. Suggestions gratefully appreciated...

Comment: Could you show your code please? Destroying/recreating the window surface is exactly what the hardware renderer does quite often. Why are you destroying your surface btw?

Comment: Problem solved --- more details in body. Thanks very much. However... I will point out that the cause of the original problem (switching between 2D and 3D rendering in the same NativeWindow not being supported) does not actually seem to be documented anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from OpenGL to CPU rendering (`ANativeWindow_lock`) and vice versa but you need to release the used `Surface` with `Surface.release()` and create a new one from your `SurfaceTexture` for the other API.

[Example app](https://github.com/StenSoft/Android-Surfacing)